# Sql table for event with calender

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to build a Sql table that hold and `sellerid` and the dates(day and time) he available.

And every time the Seller add a date(day and time) that he is available it will be added to the table.

I thought to use this table:

```
EVENTS

sellerid   date
123456     5/12/2013 8:10:00
121212     9/5/2013  19:40:00
123456     4/12/2013 12:00:00
```

But my issue is with the select that get this data. I want to get all the items with something like:

```
SELECT * From Events
```

But i am afraid that this will take too much time. so i want to know if this is a good way to achieve what i want.Or is this way will take a lot of time?

I am using MySql.

Comment: Why don't you select events *by seller ID*?

Comment: because i need both of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the full data (without filters), I would suggest you to select "chunks" of data:

```
select * from events limit 0, 1000; -- The first thousand rows
select * from events limit 1000, 1000; -- The next thousand rows
...
```

If you need to filter your data, you have to be sure you have the appropriate indexes in your table. Specifically, you need to index both the fields in your table. If you haven't already created your indexes:

```
alter table events
    add index idx_sellerId(sellerId),
    add index idx_date(date)
```

This should speed up things when you filter both by `sellerId` and `date`:

```
select * from events where sellerId=123456;
select * from events where date between '2013-5-12 00:00:00' and '2013-5-12 23:59:59'
```

I would separate the `date` and the `time` part stored in your `date` field, but that's only me.

Comment: And the Table it self is good? or there is other options to implement what i want?

Comment: @MTA I don't see anything wrong with your table. Since your `events` table holds the minimum data you need (`sellerId` and `date`), I think you have the seller details in some other table (do you? if don't, do it: keep your data normailzed). Besides that, MySQL by itself has no trouble dealing with big datasets (I've used selects that return a million rows without a hickup), but of course the client you are using may have some issues with big datasets. That's why I suggest you use the "chunk" method. Check the usage of `SELECT... LIMIT...`: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the amount of data (rows), if its a simple query like `SELECT * FROM table` it should not take too much unless you have hundred of thousands.

Anyway you should think about filter the query between dates if you've lots of data.
Maybe any MySQL expert cant tell you more but I've dealed with 10.000 rows and it loads very quickly.

Answer (score 1):

I guest that you will be filtering the data by a sellerId. If you create an index on this field you should not face any inefficiencies even with huge row numbers.